# Pandas: convert a multiindex column headers into normal column header?

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame looks like this, with columns header being MultiIndex, (True, False are boolean type).

```
    date         a            value
id                   False           True
0    2013-11-26  0   346.749819      0.000000
1    2013-11-27  1   1786.449591     21442.388942
2    2013-11-28  1   677837.782372   92998.909207
3    2013-11-29  0   731443.020535   322093.419644
4    2013-11-30  1   18082.124124    11637.523334
```

How can I easily make it into this:

```
id   date        a   value: False    value: True
0    2013-11-26  0   346.749819      0.000000
1    2013-11-27  1   1786.449591     21442.388942
2    2013-11-28  1   677837.782372   92998.909207
3    2013-11-29  0   731443.020535   322093.419644
4    2013-11-30  1   18082.124124    11637.523334
```

The column names are not important, as I can modify them later using `rename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If names aren't important, you could do this, which will reset the row index, and replace the MultiIndex columns with a tuple with each level.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = list(df.columns)
```

Comment: I used `df.columns = [str(x) + str(y) for x, y in list(df.columns)]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more pythonic way of flattening those multiindex columns in a dataframe:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(' : '.join)
```